# Evaluating datetime register during trigger event

Tags: stored-procedures, triggers, db2, db2-zos

I was testing the following behaviour for datetime special register (stated [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_rules4specialregisters.html))

> If the SQL statement in which a datetime special register is used is
>   in a user-defined function or stored procedure that is within the
>   scope of a trigger, Db2 uses the timestamp for the triggering SQL
>   statement to determine the special register value.

So i crated a table with a timestamp field, a stored procedure (native sql) that is inserting the same 10 rows to the table and the tamestamp column is given the value of "current timestamp". Then i created a trigger on some other table (after insert trigger).

The result is 10 rows with increasing timestamp. I expected the timestamp to be  the same as in my interpretation the stored procedure was in the scope of a trigger.

Can you help me what this statement means?

---

```
create trigger date_check 
    after insert on test
    for each row mode db2sql
    call date_sp2() 

create procedure date_sp2()
     language sql
     BEGIN
        declare i smallint default 0; 
        my_loop: LOOP 
          insert into empty_char values('Y','Y','Y','Y',current date, current timestamp);
          SET I = I + 1;
          IF I = 10 THEN LEAVE my_loop; 
          END IF;
        END LOOP my_loop;
     END
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that note 1 applies

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_currenttimestamp.html#fntarg_1

> If this special register is used more than one time within a single SQL statement, or used with CURRENT DATE or CURRENT TIME within a single statement, all values are based on a single clock reading. ¹
>
> ¹ Except for the case of a non-atomic multiple row INSERT or MERGE statement.

Comment: I appreciate your research, but its not entirely satisfactory tome. To be honest I am waiting a scenario with trigger and udf/proc where it is demonstrated that timestamp is derived once.